# SQL: Truncating Highest Values in a Group

Tags: sql

With example data set below, I am curious as to whether there is a way to remove the two sets of highest values for each quarter. For the data set below.... remove the 2016Q1 MOB 26 and 25... for 2016Q2 remove all the MOB 19s and 18s... Is this possible in SQL?

```
Quarter MOB Amount
2016Q1  26  18000
2016Q1  25  14300
2016Q1  24  8520
2016Q1  23  15200
2016Q1  22  3000
2016Q2  19  6000
2016Q2  19  5500
2016Q2  18  7800
2016Q2  18  2220
2016Q2  17  9530
2016Q2  17  4000
2016Q2  16  8900
2016Q2  16  4550
```

Comment: **What** SQL? SQL is just a standard; it's not a concrete implementation, which you're presumably using.

Comment: Sample data is great, but also specify the expected result! And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: What does *remove the two sets of highest values* mean: DELETE from the table or a SELECT with a filter in WHERE?

Comment: @dnoeth I suppose it should be delete since the topic is truncating. But anyways good question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you use SQL-Server, you can do it with a [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) and [Row_number()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) to identify the two highest sets.

**Test data**

```
create table dbo.highest (Kvartal varchar(50),MOB int , amount int )
insert into dbo.highest
values
('2016Q1', 26 ,18000),
('2016Q1', 25 ,14300),
('2016Q1', 24 ,8520 ),
('2016Q1', 23 ,15200), 
('2016Q1', 22 ,3000 ),
('2016Q2', 19 ,6000 ),
('2016Q2', 19 ,5500 ),
('2016Q2', 18 ,7800 ),
('2016Q2', 18 ,2220 ),
('2016Q2', 17 ,9530 ),
('2016Q2', 17 ,4000 ),
('2016Q2', 16 ,8900 ),
('2016Q2', 16 ,4550 )
```

> Thanks to dnoeth for also specifying that dense_rank can be used.

**SQL Delete Dense_Rank()**

```
with deletehighest as (
select *,DENSE_RANK() over(partition by Kvartal order by MOB desc) as densern from  dbo.highest
)

delete from deletehighest
where densern <= 2
```

**SQL Delete Row_number()**

```
  with deletehighest as (
select ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by kvartal order by MOB desc) as rn,MOB,Kvartal from (
select distinct Kvartal,MOB from dbo.highest
) z
)

delete from a
from dbo.highest a
inner join deletehighest b on a.Kvartal = b.Kvartal and a.MOB = b.MOB and b.rn in(1,2)
```

Comment: Better use `DENSE_RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER`, then you simply `DELETE FROM deletehighest`

Comment: @dnoeth Thats also a possiblity yes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case of MySQL:

```
DELETE tq FROM tq
  INNER JOIN (
               SELECT *
               FROM (SELECT
                       t.*,
                       CASE
                       WHEN @quarter != t.quarter
                         THEN @rownum := 1
                       ELSE CASE WHEN @mob != t.mob
                         THEN @rownum := @rownum + 1
                            ELSE @rownum := @rownum
                            END
                       END                   AS rank,
                       @quarter := t.quarter AS var_quarter,
                       @mob := t.mob         AS var_mob
                     FROM Tq t
                       JOIN (SELECT
                               @rownum := NULL,
                               @quarter := '',
                               @mob := '') r
                     ORDER BY t.quarter, t.mob DESC) x
               WHERE x.rank <= 2) tqlimit ON tq.quarter = tqlimit.quarter AND tq.mob = tqlimit.mob;
```